# My UISlider doesn't seem to move all the way up or down when I build and run my app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

I don't know if this is an issue with Xcode but both my UISliders don't seem to move whenever I build and run my app. I have created a minimum and maximum values for the sliders and the bars are coloured. But when I run the app the bars of the sliders disappear and only the slider button is visible. I can't seem to move it all the way to the left or to the right. It moves slightly only in either direction.
The UISliders do not have an IBAction yet so they aren't linked to code. I don't know what else it can be

Comment: Sounds like you have not given your sliders Width (or Leading and Trailing) constraints.

Comment: @DonMag this fixed it, thanks so much! I didn't set a width constraint just a height. I thought width wouldn't be needed since the bar is already set.

Answer (score -1):

As per OP's comments...

The issue was due to not providing a Width for the `UISlider`

Needs to be done with either a Width constraint or Leading & trailing constraints.